# How to switch from onesided document to twosided

Tags: thesis

I was writing my thesis as a one-sided document, but I want to print it and I want to switch to two-sided document. I added twoside after loadclass but doesn't help. I am not an expert in LaTeX, maybe there is an issue in my code?

First file code:

```
\message{*** [aghdpl.cls] ---  (MSz, GJN)  v0.22 <05.04.2011>  ***}       
\newif\ifpdflatex\pdflatexfalse
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} % 
\ProvidesClass{aghdpl} 
\DeclareOption{pdflatex}{\pdflatextrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}} 
\ProcessOptions\LoadClass[a4paper,twoside]{report} 

\RequirePackage{times}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage[usenames]{color}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{tocloft}

\geometry{lmargin=30mm, rmargin=20mm, tmargin=25mm, bmargin=25mm, foot=10mm, head=10mm}
\definecolor{Green}{rgb}{0.1,0.5,0.1}

\def\shorttitlePL#1   {\gdef\@shorttitlePL{#1}}
\def\shorttitleEN#1   {\gdef\@shorttitleEN{#1}}
\def\shortauthor#1    {\gdef\@shortauthor{#1}}
\def\titlePL#1        {\gdef\@titlePL{#1}}
\def\titleEN#1        {\gdef\@titleEN{#1}}
\def\facultyEN#1      {\gdef\@facultyEN{#1}}
\def\facultyPL#1      {\gdef\@facultyPL{#1}}
\def\thesistypePL#1   {\gdef\@thesistypePL{#1}}
\def\thesistypeEN#1   {\gdef\@thesistypeEN{#1}}
\def\supervisorPL#1   {\gdef\@supervisorPL{#1}}
\def\supervisorEN#1   {\gdef\@supervisorEN{#1}}
\def\acknowledgements#1   {\gdef\@acknowledgements{#1}}
\def\departmentPL#1   {\gdef\@departmentPL{#1}}
\def\departmentEN#1   {\gdef\@departmentEN{#1}}

% \thesisheaders
% 
% \pagestyle{fancy}

%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\linespread{1.3}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\m@th\bullet$}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\titlepages}{%

\newpage \titlepage 

\begin{center}

{\sffamily{\Large{\bfseries{\textsc Akademia G\'{o}rniczo-Hutnicza\\[2mm]
im. Stanis\l{}awa Staszica w Krakowie}}}

\vspace*{1mm}\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}\vspace*{1mm}

{\large \@facultyPL}}\\\vspace*{2mm}
{\large\textsc{\@departmentPL}}\vspace*{1cm}

\ifpdflatex\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{agh}
\else\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{agh}
\fi
\vspace*{1cm}

{\huge\scshape \@thesistypePL}\\\vspace*{2cm}

{\LARGE\scshape \@author}\\\vspace*{2cm}

{\LARGE{\bfseries\scshape \@titlePL}}\\\vspace*{3cm}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[!h]{6cm} 
\large{\scshape Promotor:}\\ \@supervisorPL
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}

\vfill{\Large Krak\'{o}w \@date}

\end{center}


\clearpage \titlepage

\begin{center}

{\sffamily{\Large{\bfseries{\textsc AGH\\[2mm]
University of Science and Technology in Krakow}}}

\vspace*{1mm}\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}\vspace*{1mm}

{\large \@facultyEN}}\\\vspace*{2mm}
{\large\textsc{\@departmentEN}}\vspace*{1cm}

\ifpdflatex\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{agh}
\else\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{agh}
\fi
\vspace*{1cm}

{\huge\scshape \@thesistypeEN}\\\vspace*{2cm}

{\LARGE\scshape \@author}\\\vspace*{2cm}

{\LARGE{\bfseries\scshape \@titleEN}}\\\vspace*{3cm}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}[!h]{6cm} 
\large{\scshape Supervisor:}\\ \@supervisorEN
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}

\vfill{\Large Krakow \@date}

\end{center}

\clearpage \titlepage

\vspace*{15cm} \vfill
\begin{flushright} 
\begin{minipage}[!h]{8cm}
{\Large \@acknowledgements}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}

\clearpage


\setcounter{page}{4}

}

\def\thesisheaders{
\fancyfoot[L]{\small \@shortauthor\quad\textit{\@shorttitlePL}}
}

\DeclareOption{en}{
\def\thesisheaders{
\fancyfoot[L]{\small \@shortauthor\quad\textit{\@shorttitleEN}}
}
}

\ProcessOptions

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape{\small \rightmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries \thepage}

\thesisheaders

\frenchspacing
\sloppy 
\widowpenalty     9999 
\clubpenalty      9999 
\flushbottom


\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\bfseries\LARGE}{\filright \LARGE\thechapter. }{0ex}{}
%odst�py: lewy, g�ra, d��
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{17mm}{19mm}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\bfseries\Large}{\filright \Large\thesection. }{0ex}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{7mm}{8mm plus 0mm minus 1mm}{4mm plus 0mm minus 1mm}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
{\bfseries\large}{\filright \large\thesubsection. }{0ex}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{7mm}{6mm}{2.5mm}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
{\bfseries\normalsize}{\filright \normalsize\thesubsubsection. }{0ex}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{7mm}{3mm}{1.5mm}


\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\bfseries\Large}
\renewcommand{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{20mm}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{19mm}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{.}
\setlength{\cftparskip}{2pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalsize}
```

And another one:

```
\documentclass[pdflatex,12pt,twoside]{aghdpl}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


% dodatkowe pakiety
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{TeX}

\lstset{
  literate={ą}{{\k{a}}}1
           {ć}{{\'c}}1
           {ę}{{\k{e}}}1
           {ó}{{\'o}}1
           {ń}{{\'n}}1
           {ł}{{\l{}}}1
           {ś}{{\'s}}1
           {ź}{{\'z}}1
           {ż}{{\.z}}1
           {Ą}{{\k{A}}}1
           {Ć}{{\'C}}1
           {Ę}{{\k{E}}}1
           {Ó}{{\'O}}1
           {Ń}{{\'N}}1
           {Ł}{{\L{}}}1
           {Ś}{{\'S}}1
           {Ź}{{\'Z}}1
           {Ż}{{\.Z}}1
}

...

\end{document}'
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help!

Comment: you have already specified `twoside` on most document classes that is all you need.  Note you should _really_ remove the space from all these definitions `\def\titlePL#1        {\gdef\@titlePL{#1}}`  the syntax of `\titlePL` if defined that way is truely weird, the argument is not given by `{}` braces  as in any normal latex command.

Comment: in fact the option in your document does not matter your class does `\ProcessOptions\LoadClass[a4paper,twoside]{report} ` so it is _always_ double sided. as it passes `twoside` to `report`

Comment: Thanks for answers! I was also wondering if I can somehow mirror my headers. Right now they are on the right side and on my left page I want to move them to the left side. Is that possible to execute quickly?

Comment: see the fancyhdr package, which you are already loading

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[!h]` minipage does not have `!h` option

Comment: You say you are not an expert, which mean syou are using a template which was written by one, and an evil one at that!